# special characters break mysql insert

Tags: php, mysql, html-sanitizing, sanitization

I have a mysql statement like this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO movies (comments, description, synopsis)
VALUES ('$_POST["comments"]', '$_POST["desc"]',$_POST["synopsis"])");
```

very simple and straightforward as you can see. The issue is when I enter special characters to the form, it doesnt insert the data to my table (using phpmyadmin to check directly if it was inserted).
for example if i put in comments textarea this value: "this is a comment"
this works
if I put instead: "what's your name? : John doe is my name"
it breaks.I know its because mysql uses the characters... any suggestions on what I should do ?

Comment: Please start here: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO movies (comments, description, synopsis) 
VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["comments"])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["desc"])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["synopsis"])."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$comments = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comments']);
$desc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['desc']);
$synopsis = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['synopsis']);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO movies (comments, description, synopsis)
VALUES ('$comments', '$desc', '$synopsis'");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$comments = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comments']);
$desc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['desc']);
$synopsis = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['synopsis']);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO movies (comments, description, synopsis)
VALUES ('$comments', '$desc', '$synopsis'");
```

For more information google "php addslashes", or look at this page looks explanatory http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php

Comment: Why `addslashes` rather than the relevant mysql function?

Comment: Changed to "mysql_real_escape_string". I put "google for php addslashes" just to guide for more information for this reason.